# Still obtaining duplicate value?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to add two vectors together if they are not duplicates of each other. If the sets at the indexes aren't equal. I add them together, however, I'm still getting duplicates. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

```
 vector<int> newvec;
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < vector.size(); i++)
        {
            for(unsigned int j = 0; j < x.vector.size(); j++) 
            {
                if(vector[i] != x.vector[j])
                {
                   newvec.push_back(vector[i]);
                   newvec.push_back(vector[j]);
                }
            }

        }
}
```

Comment: Consider two vectors `a, b`, both containing `{0, 1}`. Since `a[0]!=b[1]`, you add both values to the new vector. And since `a[1]!=b[0]`, you add both values to the new vector again. Your logic simply isn't sound. You need to undeestand the difference between "this value has no duplicates" and "this value has one other value which is not a duplicate".

Answer (score 1):

You have to iterate through both vectors at the same time.

Right now you're comparing each element of the first vector to every element of the second vector.